# Encrypting with GPG using PHP

Tags: php, windows, exec, gnupg

I need help encrypting files in PHP using GPG. I have done some research but I can't find a solution yet.

Using GPG in command line works perfectly but when I try from PHP I get a return value 2.
I have also tried passing '--yes --always-trust' as extra switches to command as suggested in one of the answers on SO but no joy.

I have tried using the gnupg function built into PHP - all the examples I've found show how to encrypt strings and not files. reading the file as a string will not work for me because I'm working on large files as big as 15MB.

I need help!

**Environment Details**

```
OS: Windows 7
PHP installation: WAMP Server 2.1
```

**Code**

```
$path = "c:\wamp\www";
$recipient = "Test user";
$encrypted_file = "c:\wamp\www\test.txt.gpg";
$decrypted_file = "c:\wamp\www\decrypted_test.txt";
$plain_file = "c:\wamp\www\test.txt";

exec('gpg --homedir $path --recipient $recipient --output $encrypted_file --encrypt $plain_file --yes --always-trust', $answer, $rtn);

var_dump($answer);
var_dump($rtn);
echo "<br />ANSWER: ".$answer;
echo "<br />RTN: ".$rtn;
```

**Output**

```
array(0) { } int(2) 
ANSWER: Array
RTN: 2
PHP User: nt authority\system
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
exec('gpg --homedir $path --recipient $recipient --output $encrypted_file --encrypt                     $plain_file --yes --always-trust', $answer, $rtn);
```

To

```
exec("gpg --homedir $path --recipient $recipient --output $encrypted_file --encrypt                     $plain_file --yes --always-trust", $answer, $rtn);
```

Notice I changed single quotes to double

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but the output is still the same

Comment: Raptor and Vascowhite thanks so much - you set me on the right path.

I was able to get it working. The problem is that the switch values needed to be within double quotes ("").

    exec("gpg --homedir \"$path\" --recipient \"$recipient\" --output \"$encrypted_file\" --encrypt \"$plain_file\" --yes --always-trust", $answer, $rtn);

Answer (score 1):

You mix up the use of single quote & double quote.

```
$path = 'c:\wamp\www';
$recipient = 'Test user';
$encrypted_file = 'c:\wamp\www\test.txt.gpg';
$decrypted_file = 'c:\wamp\www\decrypted_test.txt';
$plain_file = 'c:\wamp\www\test.txt';
```

And in this line:

```
exec("C:\\Wamp\\WWW\\gpg --homedir $path --recipient $recipient --output $encrypted_file --encrypt                     $plain_file --yes --always-trust", $answer, $rtn);
```

Use double quote when the string is needed to be parsed by PHP (take a note of Escape characters); use single quote when the string does not need to be parsed.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but the output is still the same

Comment: double check the execution rights? Also, you should provide the full path of GPG for `exec()` function.

Comment: Execution rights: the PHP user is nt authority\system - I guess the user should have execution rights.
Full path of GPG: I have a local version of GPG running in C:\Wamp\WWW following the steps suggested (http://www.glump.net/howto/gpg_intro)

Comment: not true. NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM does NOT necessarily have the rights. You should double check the folder access rights. For example, in some cases, the PHP user has no rights on C:\WINDOWS\Temp